# update MongoDB for every 30sec with remote JSON data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb

I'm parsing remote JSON data into MongoDB, Actually i'm parsing dynamic JSON data,but i want to update MongoDB for every 30 Sec with dynamic data.

parsing JSON data like this

```
require 'open-uri'

require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("url_of_json_service").read)
```

how i can update MongoDB for every 30sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rufus-schedular gem and it's working fine.

in Gemfile

```
gem 'rufus-scheduler', :require => "rufus/scheduler"
```

in config/initializers/reminder_sheduler.rb

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.cron("0 5 * * *") do
  Model.send_reminder_email
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is a common solution for recurring jobs, from the cron-job you can start either a script/runner Rails script or a rake task.

I should mention that with Cron the finest granularity is 1 minute.

Another solution would be to create a background job, which runs as a [Daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) and basically runs a continuous loop: loading the remote JSON, sleeping for 30 seconds, loading the remote JSON, sleeping, ...

Check out these Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

Cron:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron